# manifest icons Line 1 not , column: 1, Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

This seems to be an old question here in Stackflow, but I can't get any posted solution to work.

The JSON validates well in validators, but I keep getting the below error. What can be the problem?

Error: `manifest icons Line 1 not , column: 1, Unexpected token.`

```json
    {
         "name": "slangoApp",
         "icons": [
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-36x36.png",
           "sizes": "36x36",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "0.75"
          },
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-48x48.png",
           "sizes": "48x48",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "1.0"
          },
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-72x72.png",
           "sizes": "72x72",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "1.5"
          },
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-96x96.png",
           "sizes": "96x96",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "2.0"
          },
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-144x144.png",
           "sizes": "144x144",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "3.0"
          },
          {
           "src": "\/android-icon-192x192.png",
           "sizes": "192x192",
           "type": "image\/png",
           "density": "4.0"
          }
         ]
        }
```

Comment: 1. Resave the file in UTF-8 encoding 2. Don't escape `/` 3. What is this format? See the [docs on icons key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the browser does not understand the MIME type of the manifest file and thus cannot find it. In Chrome DevTools > Network > Headers > Content-Type, the content-type of the manifest must match the actual manifest file extension (`.json` or `.webmanifest`).

In ASP.NET, you need to declare the file type in `web.config`:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: I have never heard of a `web.config` file. After looking it up you seem to be giving an answer that is specific to ASP.NET websites, as opposed to a more generalizable answer about having your server set the mimeType for these files.

Answer (score 0):

manifest.json should be present in a directory where your index.html is present. Not in any other directory. If you are using react its possible that you might have misplaced it in src directory.

Answer (score -1):

This `"name": "slangoApp",` shoulb be like this `"name": "slangoapp",`
Please remember it should not contain uppercase letters of spaces.